# Difference Between Ruderman-Kittel-Kasuya-Yosida (RKKY) Interaction and Kondo Effect

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, disorder

The question is in the title. I don't understand the difference between these two effects.

Based on my understanding, the Kondo Effect is where the conduction electrons effectively screen a local magnetic impurity by forming a cloud of opposite polarization around it.

The [RKKY interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) seems to be the same thing: conduction electrons form polarized rings around the impurity, effectively screening it.

Comment: Notice that the picture that you phrased for the Kondo effect is slightly inaccurate: The screening cloud is not 'polarized' opposite to the magnetic impurity but the cloud and impurity spins form a many-body singlet state. Then there is no more local moment (or cloud moment) that is polarized in some way, and therefore we have a Pauli paramagnet.
The situation you describe should be different from this because it suggests that there is some kind of ground state degeneracy ($E_{\uparrow\downarrow}=E_{\downarrow\uparrow}$), but the many-body singlet state is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 2):

The [RKKY interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) is a generalization of the Kondo calculation in the case of two spins : it deals with finding the correct form of the interaction between two magnetic impurities via the Fermi sea.

In this case you have a competition between two effects : the Kondo that describes the screening of each impurity bu the Fermi sea of electrons, and the RKKY interaction that tunes Ferro or Antiferromagnetic order.

Comment: Is the analogy-- Thomas-Fermi Screening:Kondo Effect::Friedel Oscillations:RKKY Interaction--correct? AKA The Kondo screening by the Fermi sea is non-exponential and oscillatory?

Answer (score 0):

This paper should be interesting for you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0225.pdf, see Figs. 3 and 4.

For a single impurity in a non-interacting bath the spatial dependence of the spin correlation function around the impurity is indeed similar to the Friedel oscillations. The envelope function shows actually power-law and exponential behavior, depending on the length and temperature scale.

The RKKY coupling and the Kondo effect have of course the same origin in the screening of the impurity by the conduction electrons. But I find it difficult to answer the main question, because it is obvious that adding another impurity spin will change the correlations compared to the single impurity case. Let's put the question differently: In what way are the RKKY interaction and the Kondo effect the same? Is it really clear?